# how to display Url inside a <apex:pageBlockTable>?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, url, pageblocktable

I created a custom object with two cloumns, name and url. I just want to dislay these inside an apex page using `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. I used the following code:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="resourcePage">
     Resources
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sentResources}" var="ca">
          <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!ca.Name}" />
          <apex:column headerValue="Url" value="{!ca.ResourceUrl__c}" />
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

But, no matter what I tried, I cannot display the url inside the `apex:pageBlockTable`. I have been stuck at this for two days, and I couldn't figure out why. In order to check whether I am retrieving the url properly, I print one of the url outside of the table :[image]
it works fine. but the url is not displaying in the table. Is there any problem in my code? How can i display the url insde the table?

EDIT:
 full vfp code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="ShowResourcesClass" action="{!getSentResources}">

        <p>{!sampleString}</p><br/>

        <apex:pageBlock id="resourcePage">
            Resources
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sentResources}" var="ca">
                <apex:column> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>                                                    
                    <apex:outputText value="{!ca.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">Url</apex:facet>                                                    
                    <apex:outputText value="{!ca.ResourceUrl__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:page>
```

And this is class that get the list :

```
public class ShowResourcesClass {

    public String sampleString {get;set;}
    public List<MailHistory__c> sentResources {get; set;}

    public PageReference getSentResources() {

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('**HTTP Request**);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            sentResources = new List<MailHistory__c>();
            List<Object> objects = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            for (Object obj: objects) {
                Map<String, Object> mapJson = (Map<String, Object>)obj;
                MailHistory__c mHistory = new MailHistory__c();
                mHistory.Id = (Id)mapJson.get('Id');
                mHistory.Name = (String)mapJson.get('Name');
                mHistory.ResourceUrl__c = (String)mapJson.get('ResourceUrl__c');
                sampleString = (String)mapJson.get('ResourceUrl__c');
                sentResources.add(mHistory);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to print it? Does it display blank values or doesn't display column at all?

Comment: as you can see from the image, it doesn't display the column at all..

Comment: @JayeshBabu Can you post your entire VF code ? And can you make sure that FLS for that field is setup correctly i.e. at least has read permission. Also how are you printing the URL outside the table i.e. are you getting the value into a string variable and then displaying it ?

Comment: @VijayGanji i have added the full code. I think the problem is in this line `mHistory.ResourceUrl__c = (String)mapJson.get('ResourceUrl__c');` line. I think the url value is not getting assigned to the `mHistory.ResourceUrl__c` field.

Comment: @JayeshBabu Yes maybe you are using the wrong JSON key. Make sure that  `ResourceUrl__c` is the JSON key. Also, it would be helpful if you can post the JSON as well.

Comment: @VijayGanji I am pretty sure that JSON key is right. Thats the reason why I assigned that to a sample string and printed it.

Comment: @JayeshBabu and how about the field level security of `ResourceUrl__c` field ? Does your profile have the read access to that field of `MailHistory__c` object.

Comment: Hey, I got the solution!!. I went to the properties of `ResourceUrl__c` field and enabled `Always require a value in this field in order to save a record` field. I dont know why this worked. But, it did. Anyway, thank you very much for everyone's responses.